# Server (IIS) logging for a single page web app built in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, iis, logging, web-applications, angular-ui-router

I have a single page web app which has close to 10 different sections like

1. discussions
2. profile
3. video

etc , each of them have their states in the router as , it has its own controller and template and the urls are like

```
 1. http://myapp/#/discussions
 2. http://myapp/#/profile
 3. http://myapp/#/video
```

when the angular app loads all the templates and js files are downloaded and at IIS only one request is made ie:

```
http://myapp/
```

but the things after  '**#**' don't get passed to server. The UI router replaces templates at the client side but I want to track how many users visit the particular sections of my web app.

I cant do that from IIS logs as no resources are requested for individual sections in short i am expecting a log entry in IIS as below when a user visits **discussion** section

```
http://myapp/discussions
```

please let me know if I am correct in this approach or should i follow some other method.

Comment: pls tell me why was it down voted? i felt am doing something wrong and i asked for a better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single page app, by definition, only makes an initial request to the server (IIS) to retrieve HTML and javascript. Subsequent interaction with your app is all handled by the javascript you loaded initially.

You won't be able to rely on your web server for tracking this. Instead, you should find something that can fire events from the javascript side, such as [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/screens).

Comment: my app is on intranet i cant access google services. So should i build my own logger engine with separate Db & services?